# How to catch exceptions by @ResponseStatus in @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking for a way to handle communications with the front end in case of error driven by `@ResponseStatus` so that

- if the response is a 400/401/403 I can log an info and send a specific message out
- if the response is a 500 I can log an error and send another specific message out

and so on.

In our Api gateway we have a `RextExceptionController` (`@ControllerAdvice`) where we handle exceptions and return our own DTO to the front end.

Everything works fine if I target single exceptions (see example below) but obviously this doesn't work if I want to target just the response HTTP status.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) {
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    apiError.setMessage("Bla bla Status 400");
    return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
}

@ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported(
  HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex,
  HttpHeaders headers,
  HttpStatus status,
  WebRequest request) {
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
    apiError.setMessage("Bla bla Status 415");
    return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
}
```

This is not a sustainable way to handle it as future development from different teams (the application is based on a micro service architecture) may throw any sort of exceptions really and I don't want to run after all the possible exceptions but to base the handler on response status.

Any tips/ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an http handler interceptor in order to intercept the http  response  after request completion and make some actions based on the status yu have , check this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor.